# BigCommerce - How to find category id at the front-end

Tags: php, e-commerce

Is there anyway to get category id (dynamically), when you are in a category page.

For example, I am expecting something like %%GLOBAL_CategoryId%%

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert and spent a lot of time looking for an answer to this without any luck. I did look at the source code of the website I was trying to edit and with luck guessed the answer. I realized this question is old, but as I mentioned I had no luck finding an answer elsewhere. In BigCommerce to get the category ID of the page you are on use:

%%GLOBAL_CatId%%

Answer (score 0):

In case there is some desperate soul coming across this antique, you can grab information from a category by checking the object {{category}} handlebars (stencil): https://bigcommerce.stoplight.io/docs/docs/502e9e7a866b8-other-objects-and-properties-overview#category